# 504 redirects when I attempt to catch in php

Tags: php, apache, curl, http-status-code-504

The problem I am having is I am trying to do a curl request to a server, and I am getting redirected to a 504 page

[image]

I am trying to catch the error as follows:

```
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  if ($httpCode==504){
    header("Location: myOwnErrorPageFor504.php"); 
}
```

This code seems to catch other error codes, such as 200 perfectly fine. I think the problem is that as soon as it is 504, it redirects to that page or something before my code goes off to check if it returned a 504? I basically just want to do something if it returns 504.

I am using apache, and php 7.0 if this is relevant. This was the accepted answer to a couple other questions like this, but it doesnt work for me, so I am asking here.

Should note my apache specs. The timeout seems to be after around 50 seconds.

Timeout in my apache is 300. 
KeepAliveTimeout is 5.

For php:Default socket timeout 120.

So I don't know if its my server. Side not, this code is querying another server, which also queries another server after that. (its an API, that then queries another API, I didn't write it, thats just what it does).

For the person who wants the full curl code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    $auth
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);



$result = curl_exec($ch);

$ch_error = curl_error($ch);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  if ($httpCode==504){
curl_close($ch);
    header("Location: contactUs.php"); 
}
if ($ch_error) {
    curl_close($ch);
   return $ch_error;


} else {

        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
}
```

Comment: It might be your server returning a 504, not the remote server.

Comment: Indeed, I should post my specs. I did think of this

Comment: You should post your full curl code

Comment: @PatrickQ Done.

Comment: I'm with aynber, looks like the timeout is probably on _your_ server.

Comment: @PatrickQ So how do I go about debugging this then? What I searched on timeouts were the things I posted. Its still the same problem I am trying to solve. Do something instead of 504.

Comment: @aynber Is there a solution to this? I also conclude it might be. However does not change that I would like to do something instead of time out.

Comment: @Lain Unfortunately, that is kind of hard to debug remotely.  Just to confirm, even though you say "I am getting redirected to a 504 page", you're not actually getting _redirected_, right?  You're staying on the same URL, you just see the error message as the output/response of your request?

Comment: Try setting `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` on your connection to a value smaller than your server/php timeout. That way the curl script will time out before your script.

Comment: @PatrickQ that is correct. Not redirected

Comment: @aynber Didn't seem to do anything. Still timed out after 50 seconds. Added both of these  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);  Both individually and together. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA by default looks for an EntityManagerFactory named entityManagerFactory. Check out this part of the Javadoc of EnableJpaRepositories or Table 2.1 of the Spring Data JPA documentation.

That means that you either have to rename your emf bean to entityManagerFactory or change your Spring configuration to:

(if you are using XML)

or

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="your.package", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")

(if you are using Java Config)